# I have a table in Word with POI-HWPF Can I insert another table into a cell in the tabel?

Tags: apache-poi, hwpf

I have a table in Word with POI-HWPF. Can I insert another table into a cell in the table?

Answer (score 1):

The `HWPF` part of `POI` is not in a stable state. You will likely not be able to insert a table into a table cell.

I developed an improved `HWPF` library for one of my clients so I know about the internal details. The files created by the public `HWPF` are likely to crash Word if they are non-trivial. Having one table is already non-trivial and modifying nested tables will definitely produce invalid output files.

I don't know, whether you can use RTF files for nested tables. But if using RTF is an option for you, it may be worth trying. With `doc` files and `HWPF` you are out of luck.

Comment: Thanks,I've worked it out! Freemarker + Xml can make it much easier

Comment: @tracis Glad you found a way around it. I did not know about Freemarker - interesting project - thanks for mentioning :-)